# What XML or JSON or ??? data format can describe a complex set of requirements?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, swagger, jsonschema

I need to express

- A passing grade in a pre-requite class, in order to access the next one.
- An exemption policy to the above, where the professor can override the requirement.
- A student can only have one such exemption in a given span of time (year)
- Students must be older than 21
- Students can only be enrolled in 3 eligible majors

Or similarly, the NY DMV has a [complex set of documents and prerequisites](http://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/prove-identity-age-permitlicense) in order to obtain a driver's license.

**Question**

- What abstract syntax will allow me to describe the rules listed above, in a platform neutral way?

**Use case**

I'm developing an app where people define eligibility rules to access certain data.  Those rules may have prerequisites, or key/value ranges to access it.

I am thinking XML, but that might become cumbersome.  Just as [swagger](http://swagger.io) has become the "easier way" to handle web services, I'm looking for a similar "easy" syntax to handle these rules.